# Include js script ONLY on woocommerce product category pages?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a script that I am loading globally to perform a simple action on a specific page. It is showing up an error in the console.log because the other pages dont have the html needed to interact with my script.

To fix this i would like to load the script ONLY on the page type needed. Which is the woocommerce product category pages.

Here is the code I am using in my functions.php file

```
function read_more_js() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/marshall-child/js/read-more.js"></script>';
}
// Add hook for front-end <head></head>
add_action('wp_footer', 'read_more_js');
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Woocommerce has the is_product_category() conditional. You should use `wp_enqueue_script()` though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can use wp_enque method no problem. I am just not sure how to make a conditional statement for the specific type of woocommerce page. IE: The product category page only.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: I wrapped my code above into  if (is_product_category()) { MY CODE } but it doesnt wana load at all for some reason when wrapped in that. No erros tho

Comment: What do u mean "on forward" ?

Comment: Id really appreciate a straight forward answer here..

Comment: I read it but i dont understand it all.

Comment: Check the script path. This is neither absolute or relative to a page (except front page).

Comment: Im putting the code into my child theme functions.php and yes in the wp_footer

Comment: Script path is okay because it loads globally and works fine when i dont add the category condition.

Comment: Yea its not working. I give up. Im just going to place the script directly into the product category archive template until i get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use wp_unqueue_script for including scripts. Last parametr `true` include this script in footer. And woocommerce has condotions functions. You need `is_product_category()` or WordPress default condition `is_tax('product_cat')`. This code should work for you:

```
function read_more_js() {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'load-more-js', esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) . '/js/read-more.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'read_more_js' );
```

Comment: Try `is_tax('taxonomy_name')`

Comment: And? In wp_enqueue_scripts hook this conditions work fine. I doing this more than 4 years. It normal practice.

Comment: Guys. `wp_enqueue_scripts` - start after `wp` hook. See [codex hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)